# Kubernetes RBAC not giving access to resource

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to give a user access to specific resources using RBAC. I have defined a role and a role-binding, both under the same namespace. Despite the context identifying to use that namespace and user, the user does not have access to the resource.

Role:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: l
rules:
- apiGroups: [v1]
  resources: [secrets]
  verbs: [get, list, create, update, patch, delete]
- apiGroups: [v1]
  resources: [pods]
  verbs: [get, watch, list]
```

Rolebinding:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: l
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: l
  namespace: default
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: l
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Context:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: xx
    server: xx
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: l
  name: l
current-context: l
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: l
  user:
    client-certificate-data: xx
    client-key-data: xx
```

Verifying a lack of permissions:

```
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=l/l-k8s-config
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "l" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
kubectl get secrets --kubeconfig=l/l-k8s-config
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets is forbidden: User "l" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
kubectl auth can-i get secrets -n default --kubeconfig=l/l-k8s-config
no
```

Edit: As I was running an older version of kubernetes, 1.21.10, my specific issue was solved by setting each apiVersion to apiVersion: [''] instead of [""] as indicated by the accepted solution.

Comment: _`in API group ""`_  this seems significant. Compare it to your role rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each resource in Kubernetes has both an api group and an api version. When see see something like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
```

`apps` is the group, and `v1` is the version.

For core resources like Pods, Secrets, etc, there is no api group, and the version is `v1`. When you create a role, you need to set the `apiGroup` to `""`. Take a look, for example, at the default `edit` role, which includes:

```yaml
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/attach
  - pods/exec
  - pods/portforward
  - pods/proxy
  - secrets
  - services/proxy
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

You need to update your role so that it reads:

```yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: myrole
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: [secrets]
  verbs: [get, list, create, update, patch, delete]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: [pods]
  verbs: [get, watch, list]
```

This is all state clearly in the error message you show in your question:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "l" cannot list resource "pods" in **API group ""** in the namespace "default"

Comment: That causes the following error (Note I am running 1.21.10):
The Role "l" is invalid: 
* rules[0].apiGroups: Required value: resource rules must supply at least one api group
* rules[1].apiGroups: Required value: resource rules must supply at least one api group

I'm also unable to see the 'edit' role in kubectl get roles --all-namespaces.

Comment: What does the `edit` ClusterRole look like in your environment?

Comment: `kubectl describe clusterrole edit`


Name:         edit
Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
              rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin=true
Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
PolicyRule:
  Resources                                        Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs

Comment: As you have perhaps discovered, you can't usefully paste code or configuration into a comment. You're always welcome to add additional information to your question. You want to look at the output of `kubectl get clusterrole edit -o yaml`, which will give you the YAML manifest. Look at how that rule grants access to Secrets and compare it to the syntax you're using. The role I've posted here works fine with the versions of Kubernetes to which I have access (all 1.24 or later).

Comment: Yep, apologies for that formatting. Thank you for all your help. `""` still seems to be a valid api group looking at that output, so I'll keep scratching my head.